# Running Twisted Tutorial and twistd

Tags: twisted

I am new to python and i am running through the twisted tutorial. Using twistd I get the following error:

```
sudo twistd -y /home/michael/Desktop/twisted_example.tac --syslog
[sudo] password for michael: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/twistd", line 4, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Twisted==12.0.0
```

I resolved some package dependencies and installation of libxslt1-dev as some other posts suggested, but this did not resolve the problem.

I sincerely hope this is not an awkwardly stupid question, but I don't understand the python system well and would be grateful for any suggestions

MM

Answer (score 1):

You have `/usr/local/bin/twistd` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/`.

This suggests that you have an *unpackaged* installation of Twisted on your system.  This is probably in conflict with a packaged installation of Twisted.

You should generally avoid installing unpackaged software on your Linux system.  If you do install unpackaged software, you should not install it in a system location like `/usr/local` (despite the fact that this is traditionally where such software is installed).  Instead, install it in your home directory - and do **not** install it as root.

Your Linux vendor packages software for a reason - it's hard to build a system out of software made by a thousand different people and have it actually work.  The packaging process gives someone upstream a chance to test different configurations and then freeze the working configurations into a form that can be reproduced exactly on your computer.

As far as the specifics of what has gone wrong on your system, my guess is that you have setuptools (or distribute) installed and you installed Twisted 12.0.0 from a tarball, as root, using `setup.py`.  This installed a setuptools-infested version of `twistd` in /usr/local/bin.  This version of `twistd` demands exactly Twisted 12.0.0 (this is not a feature of `twistd` on its own, setuptools introduces it) but it finds whatever version of Twisted you have in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages instead, then fails.

The details may actually be a bit different, since the traceback in your question doesn't actually include enough information to really know how your system is set up.

The solution is to remove all the Twisted-related files installed in /usr/local and use the system-provided package of Twisted instead.  If that version isn't new enough, then you may want to upgrade your Linux distribution or find a newer packaged version of Twisted provided by a third-party (eg https://launchpad.net/~twisted-dev/+archive/ppa for Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul, I removed the twisted files from /usr/local and reinstalled twisted from synaptic. I started this project last summer holidays but didn't progress very far, so the files were hanging around since then. Thankyou for the advice on package management, although as a mathematician, I am often reduced to following howtos fairly closely. I appreciate the time you took to answer the question and the intelligent advice you gave me. - Michael

Comment: Better still, run your python stuff under a virtualenv to keep them from stepping on each other. http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/

Answer (score 0):

You have to install python-pkg-resources package

Comment: Thanks Fourat, I checked and these were installed, but fortunately the second post set me on the right path - michael